# How to prove trace of inverse matrix is matrix decreasing on positive definite matrix.

Tags: convex-optimization, inverse, trace

In [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), Boyd & Vandenberghe 3.6 "Convexity with respect to generalized inequalities", example 3.46 says that :  $\textbf{tr}(X^{-1})$ is matrix decreasing on $S^n_{++}$.

In the book, page 109 and 110

> [image: matrix monotone functions definition]
>
> [image: 3 examples in the book]

Which means if $X,Y$ are positive definite matrices, and $Y-X$ is positive semidefinite matrix, if $Y\neq X$, then $\textbf{tr}(X^{-1}) > \textbf{tr}(Y^{-1})$.

How to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: or give the link: http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys.

Answer (score 1):

Form Convex optimization we know that $f(X)=\textbf{tr}(X^{-1})$ is convex on $S^n_{++}$.

According to First-order condition: $f(X)\geq f(Y) + \nabla f(Y) \cdot (X-Y), \forall X,Y \in S_{++}^n$.

Which implies: $\textbf{tr}(X^{-1}) \geq \textbf{tr}(Y^{-1}) + \dfrac{\partial \textbf{tr}(Y^{-1})}{ \partial Y} \cdot (X-Y) = \textbf{tr}(Y^{-1}) + (-Y^{-2T}) \cdot (X-Y) = \textbf{tr}(Y^{-1}) + (Y^{-2T}) \cdot (Y-X)  = \textbf{tr}(Y^{-1}) + \textbf{tr}(Y^{-2} \cdot (Y-X))  $.

$\textbf{tr}(Y^{-2} \cdot (Y-X)) \geq 0 $, since both $Y^{-2}$ and $(Y-X)$ are positive semidifinite matrices.

So $\textbf{tr}(X^{-1}) \geq \textbf{tr}(Y^{-1}) $, if $X,Y$ are positive definite and $Y-X$ is positive semidefinite.